# Why do a set not trigger a store change?

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx, angular8

My store is like this

```
export interface State extends EntityState<featureModels.IModel> {
  selectedModelsId: Set<number>;
  isLoading?: boolean;
  error?: any;
}
```

I have the following action :

```
export class SelectModels implements Action {
  public readonly type = ActionTypes.SelectModels;
  constructor(public payload: {modelsIds: Array<number>}) {}
}
```

And the action trigger this reducer

```
const SELECT_MODELS = (state: State, action: featureAction.SelectModels) => {
  console.log(new Set([...Array.from(state.selectedModelsId), ...action.payload.modelsIds]));
  return {
    ...state,
    selectedModelsId: new Set([...Array.from(state.selectedModelsId), ...action.payload.modelsIds]),
  };
};
```

The action is dispatched correctly,
The log is fine, it display what I want.

But in the redux inspector, I see that there is no change in the state. But it should actually change, since instead of having an empty Set, I should have a set with some value (like the console.log display)

why ?

**EDIT 1:**

I tried a simple :

```
  return {
    ...state,
    selectedModelsId: 1234,
  };
```

but

```
  return {
    ...state,
    selectedModelsId: new Set(3),
  };
```

does not

**EDIT 2 :**

```
const SELECT_MODELS = (state: State, action: featureAction.SelectModels) => {
  console.log(new Set([...Array.from(state.selectedModelsId), ...action.payload.modelsIds]));
  console.log({
    ...state,
    selectedModelsId: new Set([...Array.from(state.selectedModelsId), ...action.payload.modelsIds])
  });
  return {
    ...state,
    selectedModelsId: new Set([...Array.from(state.selectedModelsId), ...action.payload.modelsIds])
  };
};
```

Even this, the log is correct with a `selectedModelsId: Set(1) {3}`, but in redux there is `(states are equal)`

**EDIT 3 :**

I changed everything to array, now it works... but why wouldn't it work with a set ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `Set` is not serializable, so it will not be read correctly by the devtools.
An array is serializable, and the devtools can read the values.

Comment: Does it changes the value in the store tho ? I believe yes ?

Comment: I believe it does